# Why is Rust still borrowing after a match statement?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
  
type Elem = i64;

enum Op {
    Num(Elem),
    Add((String, String)),
}

type Statements = HashMap<String, Op>;

fn main() {
    let mut statements = Statements::new();
    statements.insert("lhs".to_string(), Op::Num(64));
    statements.insert("op".to_string(), Op::Add(("lhs".to_string(), "rhs".to_string())));
    statements.insert("rhs".to_string(), Op::Num(64));
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    let mut op_name = "op";

    loop {
        let result: Elem;
        match statements.get(op_name).unwrap() {
            Op::Num(_) => {
                panic!("{}: Did not expect Num", op_name);
            },
            Op::Add((lhs, rhs)) => {
                if let Op::Num(lhs_value) = statements.get(lhs).unwrap() {
                    if let Op::Num(rhs_value) = statements.get(rhs).unwrap() {
                        result = lhs_value + rhs_value;
                    } else {
                        stack.push(op_name);
                        op_name = rhs;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    stack.push(op_name);
                    op_name = lhs;
                    continue;
                }
            },
        };
        if let Some(new_op_name) = stack.pop() {
            *(statements.get_mut(op_name).unwrap()) = Op::Num(result);
            op_name = new_op_name;
        } else {
            println!("Result: {}", result);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me the following compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `statements` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> minimal.rs:43:15
   |
22 |         match statements.get(op_name).unwrap() {
   |               ----------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
43 |             *(statements.get_mut(op_name).unwrap()) = Op::Num(result);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^-------^^^^^^^^^
   |               |          |
   |               |          immutable borrow later used by call
   |               mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I was expecting the borrowing to end with the `match` statement, since I do not see how I could still access the result of the borrowing after this statement. Why is the value still being borrowed *after* the `match` statement?

Is there something I could do to make my code above work?

Comment: [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns `Option<&V>`. The type of `op_name` seems to be `&str`, and by reassigning `op_name` in the `match` it retains the borrow on the `statements.get(op_name)` even after `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you'll find it difficult to work with strings and strings references. I would rather switch to some type for your `HashMap` keys that would be small, and copyable, like an integer number. This way you'll not be required to deal with references and mutability - you can just copy your integers with little to no cost.

I resolved your compilation errors, but the overall code becomes more convoluted. Basically now each insert into the hash map will give you a unique integer ID of the operation. You can only query operations from the hash map using this provided ID. It also requires you to push statements in your hash map in the order of appearance. You can't insert `add(lhs, rhs)` unless you already know IDs of both `lhs` and `rhs`

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
  
type Elem = i64;
type StatementId = usize;
enum Op {
    Num(Elem),
    Add((StatementId, StatementId)),
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct StatementsRecord {
    record: HashMap<StatementId, (String, Op)>,
    next_statement_id: StatementId,
}

impl StatementsRecord {
    fn insert(&mut self, name: String, operation: Op) -> StatementId {
        self.record.insert(self.next_statement_id, (name, operation));
        self.next_statement_id += 1;
        self.next_statement_id - 1 // return id of newly stored operation
    }
    fn get(&self, id: &StatementId) -> Option<&(String, Op)> {
        self.record.get(id)
    }
    fn get_mut(&mut self, id: &StatementId) -> Option<&mut (String, Op)> {
        self.record.get_mut(id)
    }
    fn update(&mut self, id: &StatementId, value: Op) {
        self.get_mut(id).unwrap().1 = value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut statements = StatementsRecord::default();
    let lhs_id = statements.insert("lhs".to_string(), Op::Num(64));
    let rhs_id = statements.insert("rhs".to_string(), Op::Num(64));
    // 64+64 = 128
    let mut op_id = statements.insert("op".to_string(), Op::Add((lhs_id, rhs_id))); 
    // (64+64) + (64+64) = 256
    let mut op_id = statements.insert("op".to_string(), Op::Add((op_id, op_id))); 
    

    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let result: Elem;
        match statements.get(&op_id).unwrap() {
            (op_name, Op::Num(_)) => {
                panic!("{}: Did not expect Num", op_name);
            },
            (op_name, Op::Add((lhs, rhs))) => {
                if let (_, Op::Num(lhs_value)) = statements.get(lhs).unwrap() {
                    if let (_, Op::Num(rhs_value)) = statements.get(rhs).unwrap() {
                        result = lhs_value + rhs_value;
                    } else {
                        stack.push(op_id);
                        op_id = *rhs;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    stack.push(op_id);
                    op_id = *lhs;
                    continue;
                }
            },
        };
        if let Some(new_op_id) = stack.pop() {
            statements.update(&op_id, Op::Num(result));
            op_id = new_op_id;
        } else {
            println!("Result: {}", result);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Result: 256
```

Comment: This was exactly right, didn't think about the string. Thanks!